# Smooth function conditions

Tags: functions, continuity, partial-derivative

A curve defined by $x=f(t)$, $y=g(t)$ is smooth if $f′(x)$ and $g′(x)$ are continuous and not simultaneously zero.

Why do we have the second condition(simultaneously zero)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of a particle moving along the curve. At any point where $x'(t) = 0$ and $y'(t) = 0$ the velocity of the particle is zero. After coming to a stop it can begin moving again in an entirely different direction. Thus even if $x'$ and $y'$ are continuous, the direction of the *tangent vector* can change abruptly at any time $t$ that both $x'$ and $y'$ both vanish, and is thus not "smooth".

Comment: WOW, I was thinking about this for hours and I finally got it thanks to you!!! THANK YOU for awesome example!

Comment: You're welcome. This is the kind of thing textbooks should say, but too often do not.